# Mass / batch - update / edit cells with in a grid

Tags: grid, edit

I am looking for some ideas on the UX of allowing a user to edit multiple cells in a grid at one time. These users may have thousands of records and they need to provide data on each record, this data may be duplicated across multiple records so I am trying to figure out a clean way to allow them to apply a value to multiple cells easily.

Hoping to not implement excel in my application.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Airtable’s solutions. If you google ‘batch update airtable’ many more examples will popup.

Here is a video:
[Batch Update with Airtable](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/115013404068-Batch-update-block)